# Load pickle in flask api

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, flask, random-forest

I have a problem with flask api **when i use it in localhost it's work well** , **but when i hosting it in pythonanywhare.com** , and run the POST method (get request in api and predict it by pickle file )**it's tell me this error** :
[image]

my api code :

````
import numpy
import json
import sys
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import sklearn.externals
import joblib
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
filename = 'tuned_rf_smote.sav'
#post a json object to see the prediction for it :
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def info():
    result = [
        {
            'Author' : 'DS team',
            'description' : 'A fraud detection model using a kaggle dataset',
        }
    ]
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/verify', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict_new_transaction():
    infile = open(filename,'rb')
    loaded_model = joblib.load(infile)
    json_ = request.json
    query_df = pd.DataFrame([json_])
    prediction = str(loaded_model.predict(query_df))
    infile.close()
    return jsonify(prediction)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,threaded=False)```
````

Comment: Does Pythonanywhere provide any logs? There should be an error message in the logs

Comment: The picture you provided does not appear to actually be valid JSON.

Comment: @dfundako i also try this but still the same 
[{"Time": 0,"V1": -1.359807134,"V2": -0.072781173,"V3": 2.536346738,"V4": 1.378155224,"V5": -0.33832077,
   "V6": 0.462387778,
   "V7": 0.239598554,
   "V8": 0.098697901,
   "V9": 0.36378697,
   "V10": 0.090794172,
   "V11": -0.551599533,
   "V12": -0.617800856,
   "V13": -0.991389847,
   "V14": -0.311169354,
   "V15": 1.468176972,
   "Amount": 149.62 }]

Comment: @ForceBru when i open api home it's work will but when i open verify in postman and put the values in body it's tell me this: 
"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."